# Inverse image of a set? On integer numbers set

Tags: general-topology, functions

My question is from the " topology without tears " book,  page 38 :
f is a function from : integer numbers to integer numbers 
$f (x)=|x|$

What is inverse image of {-5} ?

Comment: Since not everyone has that book, or access to that book, it would be nice if you could write down the problem itself, or at least the definition of $f$.

Comment: Sorry, l edited it... even though the book is available online,  but my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $f^{-1}(\{-5\})=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\,\,;\,\, |n|=-5 \}=\varnothing$ because for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ you have $|n|\geq 0.$

Comment: I asked for inverse image of {-5} NOT {5}. I think it should not be exist

Comment: Yeah I edited that too lately, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Um, unless I misunderstand, as there is no x such that f(x) = -5 the inverse image of {-5} is the empty set.

But I'm not familiar with the book so there may be something to the definition of "inverse image" that I'm misinterpreting.